# Encrypt byte array using vigenere cipher in java

Tags: java, file, encryption, byte, vigenere

I have to encrypt some file (jpg) using vigenere cipher. I wrote some code, but after encryption and decryption my file is corrupted. The first 1/4 of image displays okay, but the rest of it is corrupted. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public byte[] encryptFile(byte[] file, String key) {
    char[] keyChars = key.toCharArray();
    byte[] bytes = file;
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        int keyNR = keyChars[i % keyChars.length] - 32;
        int c = bytes[i] & 255;
        if ((c >= 32) && (c <= 127)) {
            int x = c - 32;
            x = (x + keyNR) % 96;
            bytes[i] = (byte) (x + 32);
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}


@Override
public byte[] decryptFile(byte[] file, String key) {
    char[] keyChars = key.toCharArray();
    byte[] bytes = file;
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        int keyNR = keyChars[i % keyChars.length] - 32;
        int c = bytes[i] & 255;
        if ((c >= 32) && (c <= 127)) {
            int x = c - 32;
            x = (x - keyNR + 96) % 96;
            bytes[i] = (byte) (x + 32);
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

reading and writing to file:

```
public void sendFile(String selectedFile, ICipher cipher, String key) {
    try {
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(client
                .getOutputStream());
        outStream.flush();
        File file = new File(selectedFile);
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        long fileSize = file.length();
        long completed = 0;
        long bytesLeft = fileSize - completed;
        String msg = "SENDING_FILE:" + file.getName() + ":" + fileSize;
        outStream.writeUTF(cipher.encryptMsg(msg, key));
        while (completed < fileSize) {
            int step = (int) (bytesLeft > 150000 ? 150000 : bytesLeft);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[step];
            fileStream.read(buffer);
            buffer = cipher.encryptFile(buffer, key);
            outStream.write(buffer);
            completed += step;
            bytesLeft = fileSize - completed;
        }
        outStream.writeUTF(cipher.encryptMsg("SEND_COMPLETE", key));
        fileStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    private void downloadFile(String fileName, int fileSize,DataInputStream input,ICipher cipher, String key) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\" + fileName);
        int bytesRead = 0, counter = 0;

        while (counter < fileSize) {
            int step = (int) (fileSize > 150000 ? 150000 : fileSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[step];
            bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                buffer = cipher.decryptFile(buffer, key);
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                counter += bytesRead;
            }
            if (bytesRead < 1024) {
                outStream.flush();
                break;
            }
        }

        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                window.handleMessage("Download sucessfully");
            }
        });
        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                window.handleMessage("Error on downloading file!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest investigating the bytes in the original vs. deencrypted file to find the difference.

Comment: Your code only works for ASCII text (32..127)

Comment: How are you reading/writing the byte array from/to the file? If you're reading/writing them through a string, then you can expect problems.

Comment: @stark the code explicitly skips non-printable-ASCII bytes.

Comment: Note that even if you assign `byte[] bytes = file`, you're still going to overwrite the original array.

Comment: @Jan the poster is attempting to encrypt/decrypt a jpg image.

Comment: I'm creating FileOutputStream and FileInputStream then use methods read(byte[])/write(byte[]). I know that this code skips non-printable ASCII bytes, but I think that It shouldn't be a problem with proper encryption/decryption

Comment: Jpeg files are not ASCII

Comment: " I know that this code skips non-printable ASCII bytes" - bingo! If true, it is the problem.

Comment: I add that this only fragment of code. I'm reading some portion of bytes from file, then encrypt it, then send it via socket, then read nex portion of bytes. And on the other side I receive bytes, make decryption, then write bytes to file

Comment: @Jan Dvorak but why it is the problem? It should only encrypt some bytes from file (and some not), but decryption should reverse this process

Comment: @Maniek If some bytes are skipped during the read (as opposed to left alone during the encoding), then how can they be preserved to the other side?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak bytes are skipped during encrypting not reading.

Comment: @Maniek I'm concerned if the file is _read_ properly.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak yes it is, I can also encrypt it using Caesar Cipher and AES and than all works fine so I assume that problem is with vigenere impl not with file reading.

Comment: Could the problem arise from the original buffer being overwritten?

Comment: What is the byte that gets corrupted?

Comment: Are you sure the _key_ only contains printable characters?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I also noticed that vigenere works fine when I'm using 4-letter key, ex "test" but when I try to use another length key it not working

Comment: What about another key with the same length, does it corrupt the same way?

Comment: No if I use 4 letter key it works. Only if key is 3 or 5 or another lenght it corrupt

Comment: Does it break at the same place no matter what the key is?

Comment: No, it can break in different place

Comment: @Maniek I believe 4-letter is a red herring (or an unfortunate consequence of your password being title-cased).

Comment: I changed the line to x = (x - keyNR % 96 + 96) % 96; but it still doesn't work

Comment: What is the key you are using?

Comment: Try fixing both modulo operations as `((x +- keyNR) % 96 + 96) % 96`, just in case the key gets weird characters inside.

Comment: I use different keys. 
keys "test" and "chuj" works
keys "teste" "tajne" "tes" doesn't works

Comment: Now i can't even open this image after change both modulo operations

Comment: maybe do you know some proper vigenere impl for byte[] ?

Comment: A "proper" Vigenere would rotate `a..z` and `A..Z`, so rotating `\x20..\x7F` is not technically a vigenere cipher (as in "over the latin alphabet"). If you don't mind producing non-text output for text input (`0x7F` is non-printable anyways), you can simply rotate all bytes modulo 2^8. This simplifies the modulo to a simple cast.

Comment: AD "can't open": if you have to re-encode, the original encoding was likely flawed.

Comment: yes but I need to encrypt a file not a text so I can't rotate only a..z and A..Z

Comment: If you don't mind encoding text to non-text, stick to modulo-256.

Comment: One more idea: how do you _transfer_ the file? Could it get mangled along the way (line-breaks et al.)?

Comment: Note that by `(x +- keyNR)` I mean `(x + keyNR)` for encoding, `(x - keyNR)` for decoding.

Comment: You can't just assume `bytesRead < 1204` implies end-of-file.

Comment: Ok I changed that, but it still doesn't work. I also noticed that when I sent the same file two times, using the same key, my output file looks different. Both are corrupted but corrupted colors are different in each image

Comment: @Maniek wrote an answer. The key gets mis-aligned if not four-byte in length (and even for four-byte keys it's just luck that it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encode the file in whatever chunks come from the disk I/O:

```
        int step = (int) (bytesLeft > 150000 ? 150000 : bytesLeft);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[step];
        fileStream.read(buffer);
        buffer = cipher.encryptFile(buffer, key);
```

But you decode the file in whatever chunks come from the network I/O:

```
        bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
        if (bytesRead >= 0) {
            buffer = cipher.decryptFile(buffer, key);
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            counter += bytesRead;
        }
```

These chunks are likely to disagree. The disk I/O may always give you full chunks (lucky for you), but the network I/O will likely give you packet-sized chunks (1500 bytes minus header).

The cipher should get an offset into the already encoded/decoded data (or encode/decode everything at once), and use that to shift the key appropriately, or this may happen:

```
original: ...LOREM IPSUM...
key     : ...abCde abCde...
encoded : ...MQUIR JRVYR...
key     : ...abCde Cdeab... <<note the key got shifted
decoded : ...LOREM GNQXP... <<output wrong after the first chunk.
```

Since the packet data size is (for Ethernet-sized TCP/IP packets) aligned at four bytes, a key of length four is likely to be always aligned.

---

another issue is that you are ignoring the number of bytes read from disk when uploading the file. While disk I/O is likely to always give you full-sized chunks (the file's likely to be memory-mapped or the underlying native API does provide this guarantee), nothing's taken for granted. Always use the amount of bytes actually read: `bytesRead = fileStream.read(buffer);`